# Forcing contours to close at edge

Tags: plotting, options, data

I have some data that I am plotting with `ListContourPlot` and I would like my contours to be closed at the edge (closing around the high value region).

A simple example:

```
ListContourPlot[{{3, 2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}},
                 Contours -> {1}, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Thick]
```

> [image: ![plot of unclosed contours](http://i.imgur.com/B8eMa5d.png)]

I know you can add e.g. `BoundaryStyle -> Black`, but it closes the whole region:

> [image]

Note that I have tried the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11368/detecting-edge-region-in-contour-plot), but that method changes the plotting method from plotting a matrix to plotting `{x,y,f(x,y)}` values, which has some undesirable results on my (much more complicated than the above example) data.

Comment: So your desired result is something like: `ListContourPlot[{{3, 2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0}}, Contours -> {1}, ContourShading -> None] /. 
 Line[x_] :> Line[Join[{{1, 1}}, x, {{1, 1}}]]` ?

Comment: Yes it is, but generalised

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in the above example the lower leftmost point has a value of 3 - it is the 'summit'. I want to close the contour around this summit, even though it is on the edge of the matrix.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Let me provide an answer and we will se if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad your array of points with value much below the lowest one, like that:

```
data = {{3, 2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
data = ArrayPad[data, 1, -10^6]

ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {1}, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Thick,
                      DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}]
```

[image]

I've also added `DataRange` so it fits primordial data set.

Comment: Thanks, this will do the trick.

Comment: @Jay Great, good luck :)